# How format a result using VLOOKUP to loop inside a single cell with an arbitrary number of search keys

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column called "Notes (Atomic weights)" with an arbitrary (0 to n) number of search keys in it.

[image]

and a corresponding Named Range called "NOTES"

[image]

How do I do a vlookup/Query or Filter such that I get the combined column called "Note Texts" (see image below)?

[image]

If there is only one search key in the Notes column, I can use

```
IF(LEN(W3)>0, VLOOKUP(W3, NOTES, 2, false) , )
```

but now I have an arbitrary number of search keys in one column. how do I approach this without splitting and creating even more cells and then stitch them all back (adding more columns is very messy, since many  other columns in my table also require the same fix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(char(10),ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("["&SPLIT(JOIN("! ",A1:A4),"![",1),D1:E3,2,0),"!"))),char(10)&"!"&char(10),0))`

[image]

Sample file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13QFnYri6d8xvL9kXw-xAP87n1kT4wh4HwxYtHftMU9g/edit#gid=2094642927

Answer (score 1):

Max's Solution works great! took me over an hour to analyse and finally understand the formula.

for my needs, I did not combine the rows and perform a single evaluation. Instead, I repeated the formula for every row using the following simplified formula (this fixes the alignment bug when there's empty rows)

```
 = JOIN(char(10), ArrayFormula( 
       IFERROR( 
           VLOOKUP("["&SPLIT( A10 ,"[]", TRUE) &"]",NOTES,2,0),
           "Error")
       ) 
   )
```

---

the following is a break down of what each part of Max's formula means.
start debugging from the inside(1) to the outside (7)

```
//(7) Finally, we TRANSPOSE the Columns into Rows
TRANSPOSE(
    //(6) Now, we SPLIT the column up with the delimiter “\n!\n”
    //    that was added during Step (1)
    SPLIT(
        //(5) we now JOIN back all the columns, adding a new line “char(10)" before every column
        JOIN(
        char(10) //prepend with new line 
            //(4) The Magic !! ARRAYFORMULA enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns
             //       Result is now displayed across multiple columns
            ,ArrayFormula(
                IFERROR(
                    //(3) We can now do a VLOOKUP for each of the split search key
                   // (but only The first result is displayed)
                    VLOOKUP(
                        “[“   //reinsert the [ back after the split
                          //(2) Now, SPLIT up everything using delimiter “!”(new Row)  And “[“ (new item)
                          &  SPLIT(
                               //******** START FROM HERE*********
                               //(1) - take all the rows of interest, and then 
                               //     JOIN them together with a “!<SPACE>” 
                               JOIN(
                                    "! "       //delimiter !<SPACE> ? 
                                     ,A1:A4) //text to join (all the rows of interests) 
                               ,"![“
                               ,TRUE) // split by each
                          ,NOTES   //Named range of interest
                          ,2             //take second second column
                          ,FALSE)
                    ,”!”) // insert ! If error
              ) //ArrayFormula
         ) //JOIN
         ,char(10)&"!"&char(10) //delimiter "\n!\n” for split 
         ,FALSE // do not split by each
    ) //SPLIT
) // TRANSPOSE
```